# Can I find a $r\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x<r^2<y$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let be a $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^+$ positive reals such that $x<y$. Can I find a $r\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x<r^2<y$ ?

Any suggestions please.

Comment: What about $x=-1$ and $y=0$?

Comment: Split cases for $y $. What happens if $y\leq 0$? What if $y>0\geq x $? What if $y>x>0$? Are there other cases?

Answer (score 1):

This would mean
$$
X = \sqrt{x} < r < Y = \sqrt{y}
$$
and $X, Y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $X \ne Y$. If I remember right, there is always at least one rational number between two different real numbers. ([Link](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Between_two_Real_Numbers_exists_Rational_Number))

Answer (score 0):

This in general is not true. This is because $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$ is not a surjective function. More specifically, for all $r<0$, this statement won't be true for some neighborhood around $r$.

For a more concrete example, pick any $x<0$ and try to find a squared rational between $x$ and $0$.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that if $y \leq 0$ there is no such $r$. If $y>0$ and $x <0$ then $r=0$. Now if $x \geq 0$, then because of the density of rational numbers you can find  a $r \in \Bbb Q, \;   \sqrt{x} < r < \sqrt{y}$ and you have $x<r^2<y$. I suppose that you do not have to prove the density of $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously $r^2\ge0$ so if $y\le0$ the required inequality can't be reached.

If otherwise $y>0$ you can consider $\sqrt y$ which is again $>0$; then you have two cases:

- $x\ge0$; in this case you have $\sqrt x<\sqrt y$ and since $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, you can find an $r\in\Bbb Q$ such that $\sqrt x<r<\sqrt y$ from which you get the conclusion;
- $x<0$; in this case you have $x<0<y$ so you can conclude simply taking $r=0$.